# I need to develop a project involving hardware which should also work the same on Windows as well as Macs. Whats the way forward?

Tags: windows, macos, webcam, audio-recording, video-encoding

Whats the best approach (read painless) that I could take?
Primarily, the application needs to record the webcam video + mic recording on the disk and compress the video using ffmpeg (or something similar).

So there is hardware involved + running a separate process for encoding.

I was seriously considering Adobe AIR - but I read on the Adobe site that it does not have permission to run other applications which can be problematic if I want to encode the video using ffmpeg.

Comment: So far I was considering writing the windows part separately (using .Net) and Mac part separately using XCode.
The functionality however between both the platforms would be identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider developing it in Java? In that case you should take a look at the [Eclipse Rich Client platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform). I have developed a couple of programs by using Eclipse RCP and I would never develop an app in Java without it. It uses SWT and jFace and provides options for exporting the app to run on OSX, Linux and Windows.

You should give it a try.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the tip on the Rich Client Framework platform.
Will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you can develop it under [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), much of it will work on both platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Qt. Simple as pie.